# how to read escape character in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Hi I have created a table in Athena with following query which will read csv file form S3.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS axlargetable.AEGIntJnlTblStaging (
  `filename` string,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"'
   ) 
LOCATION 's3://ax-large-table/AEGIntJnlTblStaging/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

But value in filename filed like `"\\emdc1fas\HR_UK\ADPFreedom_Employee_20141114_11.04.00.csv"`

When I read this table my values appears like

```
"\emdc1fasHR_UKADPFreedom_Employee_20141114_11.04.00.csv"
```

where I missing all the escape character (backslash) from the value.

How can I read the value which will show me the actual value with escape character.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need the escaping, you can set the escape character to something unrelated (for example `"|"`).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS axlargetable.AEGIntJnlTblStaging (
  filename string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '|'
   ) 
LOCATION 's3://ax-large-table/AEGIntJnlTblStaging/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```